# Disable Directory Browsing using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

in my server I have a series of folders. I would deny the access to all this folders. How can I do? What rule I have to use?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you keeping these folders in your web server's document root? Why not move them somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add one line in your .htaccess root:

```
deny from all
```

**@QUESTION:**

if you want to retain access for yourself:

```
allow from 192.168.1.1
```

subsitute in your real IP for the one i gave in the example.

so all together:

```
deny from all
allow from YOUR_IP
```

**@QUESTION2:**

if you deny access to a directory, you are denying access to all of the nodes in that directory like the "pages". if you are saying you want to deny access to a folder in the same level directory as the pages, move the htaccess to inside of that folder (simplest)

**@EDIT:**

Open your .htacces file
Look for Options Indexes
If Options Indexes exists modify it to Options -Indexes or else add **Options -Indexes** as a new line
The directory browsing feature should be disable by now

http://www.techiecorner.com/106/how-to-disable-directory-browsing-using-htaccess-apache-web-server/

Comment: I tried but in this way everything is blocked. I can't access to anything neither to the page

Comment: When I try to open one page it show me 403 forbidden. I would deny the access ONLY to directory and not to page. I want page showed...

Comment: go to http://google.com  SEARCH: what is my ip.  copy that address into the allow from line.

Comment: I would show to OTHER only page.what I would do is  Disable Directory Browsing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8692/discussion-between-dan-kanze-and-mazzy)

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your .htaccess file,

```
Options -Indexes
```