# Invalid Url Redirection

Tags: php

I have different folders in the site I am making.

What if the user tries to enter that folder, How would I not let them see what's inside?

Or can I redirect them into another page saying that they don't have the permission to access the folder/ invalid url?

I read something about htaccess but I dunno how that one works.

I am currently doing some trick (like adding index.php in  the folders with a message saying they don't have permission to access) to every folder.

But it's kind of a pain. And I believe there's an easier method.

Comment: this is pretty easy with .htaccess.. learn about htacess, it is simple and provide you more complex solutions.. Also take a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627196/disable-directory-browsing-using-htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627196/disable-directory-browsing-using-htaccess)

Comment: .htaccess files are the way to go if you want to restrict access to folders or files. custom .php pages that check if a user is authenticated and authorized or not are also common. why is the folder in the web root if  nobody should be able to access it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the contents of the folders:

- If it contains php or configuration files that are never to be opened directly (or anything else that never needs to be requested directly by the browser), you should not put them in the web-root;
- If it contains assets that are included in html but you do not want the visitor to browse the directory, you should configure your web-server so that directory browsing is disabled;
- If only certain logged-in users should be able to open certain files, you should handle that in the file itself, not on the directory level.

If you cannot move your directory out of the web-root but nothing in it needs to be accessible by the browser, you can put an `.htaccess` file in that directory with just the following contents:

```
deny from all
```

Comment: I tried creating an htaccess file and I guess, I succeeded. I searched the web how to do it but dunno. The file I am including does not work? Or does it have something to do with the file extension? I am using .php instead of .html. Does it matter?

Comment: @GeromeGibsTeodosio I don't understand what the exact problem is. You can include files from `.htaccess` protected directories without any problems.

Comment: It says something like this.

Not Found

The requested URL /mysite/sdsd was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Instead of loading the custom page, it loads an simple error page.
I am using WAMP server to test my site.
I dunno if that's the problem

Comment: @GeromeGibsTeodosio How does that relate to your question about protecting directories?

Comment: I read that you have something more to do for .htaccess to work on WAMP server. But it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you should accomplish on a server level.

Basically restraining access to these folders on UNIX (`chmod -r`) for example will take care of this for you.